# pipeline ci/cd for pushing a docker image to docker hub

Tags: spring-boot, docker, cicd, dockerhub

i'm trying to create a pipeline ci/cd gitlab for a spring boot project to Build a Docker Image and Push to Docker Hub so i have 3 stages: build , build docker-image and push docker-image                             every time i pass the 2 first stage : build , build docker-image but the third stage no and i have this error:
"$ docker push rajvis962/demo:latest
An image does not exist locally with the tag: rajvis962/demo
The push refers to repository [docker.io/rajvis962/demo]
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1"

the output of build docker-image is:

```
#6 DONE 5.5s
#4 [2/2] COPY target/*.jar /
#4 DONE 4.2s
#7 exporting to image
#7 exporting layers 0.1s done
#7 writing image sha256:a6845b953aa0804e14d7ec86bf7d5ae6d0a735c89adb84881ecc2e7b2e2261bc done
#7 naming to docker.io/rajvis962/demo:latest done
#7 DONE 0.1s
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```

the output of the first stage is :

```
 [INFO] The original artifact has been renamed to /builds/krim_/pipeline-cicd-springboot-project/target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  18.096 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-15T02:34:00Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:04
Uploading artifacts...
target/: found 36 matching artifact files and directories 
WARNING: Upload request redirected                  location=https://gitlab.com/api/v4/jobs/6176432077/artifacts?artifact_format=zip&artifact_type=archive new-url=https://gitlab.com
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=request redirected
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=6176432077 responseStatus=201 Created token=glcbt-65
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```

i have an account in docker hub named "rajvis962"  and repository "helloworld"
when i execute this command : docker images i just get this:

REPOSITORY                 TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
docker/welcome-to-docker   latest    c1f619b6477e   3 months ago   18.6MB

my .gitlab-ci.yml file is:

```
image: maven:latest
stages:
  - build
  - build-docker-image
  - push-image-to-docker-hub

build-java-project:
  stage: build
  script:
    - "mvn package"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/

build-docker-image:
  stage: build-docker-image
  script:
    - docker info
    - ls -l target/
    - docker build -t rajvis962/demo:latest  .
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
Push Docker Image to DockerHub:
  stage: push-image-to-docker-hub
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD"
  script:
    - docker info
    - docker push rajvis962/demo:latest
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
```

my dockerfile is:

```
FROM openjdk
COPY target/*.jar /
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/*.jar"]
```

An image does not exist locally with the tag while pushing image to local registry: how can i solve it i spent many time in search but with no solution

Comment: Did you try to Build the Docker Image Locally ?

Comment: @Mohamedaminebenhassen thanks i solve it : the probelm was that  gitlab ci/cd pipelines are isolated from each other and image that icreate in the build docker-image might not be available in the push docker-image , so i use artifacts for the caching between the stages

Comment: @Mohamedaminebenhassen are yu familiar with bitbucket and pipeline cicd gitlab

Comment: yes i worked with them both but on a separate occasions

Comment: @Mohamedaminebenhassen can you help me i want to use a pipeline cicd gitlab with my bitbucket repo  so i  i create a blanck project gitlab and then go to settings -> mirroring repository and fill the fiels with url bitbucket and username of bitbucket and password and then add a file .gitlab-ci.yml to this project the problem is the state of the mirrored repo in the list of "mirroring repo" is : error

Comment: @Mohamedaminebenhassen  error: "Some refs have diverged and have not been updated on the remote: refs/heads/main"

Comment: this is usually means that changes have been made to the branches in both repositories(the local and the remote), and they are not in sync